# Laravel - Eloquent Code location - controller or model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to decide on something, where to put database logic, in the controller or model when using the eloquent orm.

In a controller I have the following method:

```
public function postAdd(){
$amodel=new myModel();
$amodel->name=Input::get('name');
$amodel->save();
$id=$amodel->id;
}
```

Which is how the guides say to use it however should this logic not go inside a method on the model rather than in the controller? I know the above still provides abstraction from the database but the bit that I'm unsure of is how reusable it then becomes... or not as the case maybe.

Would it therefore be a better option to do the following:

```
public function postAdd(){
$amodel=new myModel();
$id = $amodel->addPost(Input::get('name'));
}
```

So I pass along information to a method on the model which does the work. This allows it to be reused and the model method changed if required without updating many lines of code?

The answer might simply be 'yes, do it like you've suggested' in which case great but I'd be interested on the standard practice when using an ORM like this.

Comment: please, try carefully reading "component interaction" section http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller's sole responsibility is handling and delegating UI requests to the Model. That's why it should be skinny. It should only contain code necessary for what it's responsible for. So thats why you should move your code to the model, or, even better and more Laravel-like solution is to use repositories in this case. ([link](http://imperativedesign.net/what-is-a-repository-and-how-does-it-work/))